# Integration by partial fractions, reducing denominator through substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

In the following case, suppose $b$ is a number and $b≠0$. Find

$$ \int{1\over(x^2+b^2)^n}\mathrm{d}x$$

The textbook uses the following substitution:

$$ x=bz$$
$$ \mathrm{d}x=b\mathrm{d}z$$

And reduces the integral to:

$$ \int{1\over(x^2+1)^n}\mathrm{d}x$$

However, given the presence of the exponent $n$ in the denominator and assuming that $n > 1$, how is it possible that the integral is reduced in the manner above?

Comment: This substitution does not make sense when $b = 0$. Is $b \neq 0$ a condition?

Comment: Yes, that would be so - good point.

Comment: Edit your post to include the condition $b \neq 0$. It will be helpful for people trying to answer your question.

Comment: The book may have made a mistake. There should be a factor of $\frac{1}{b^{2n-1}}$ in front of the second integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $b=0
 $ we have nothing to do (the integral depend only by $x
 $.). Assuming $b\neq0
 $, we have $$\int\frac{1}{\left(x^{2}+b^{2}\right)^{n}}dx\overset{x=bz}{=}\int\frac{b}{\left(b^{2}z^{2}+b^{2}\right)^{n}}dz=\frac{1}{b^{2n-1}}\int\frac{1}{\left(z^{2}+1\right)^{n}}dz
 $$ so we have the constant $1/b^{2n-1}
 $ outside the integral.

Comment: There should not be a $b$ inside your integral. You already cancelled it before taking $\frac{1}{b^{2n-1}}$ outside.

Comment: Although the expression makes sense in variable terms, I am curious as to why it only seems to work (assuming that $n > 1$) when $b=1$. If the constant $\frac{1}{b^{2n-1}}$ can be moved inside the integral, then for argument's sake let $x=1$, $n=2$ and $b=2$. Then $f(x)=\frac{1}{25}$ in the original integral and $f(x)=\frac{1}{32}$ in the second. On the other hand, when $b=1$ and holding all other terms constant, $f(x)=\frac{1}{4}$ for both integrals and the expression indeed holds true. Why would this be the case?

Comment: @DavidLee The equality holds for the integrals, not for the functions. Obviously, if $b=1$ the functions are the same, but only in this case.